# Sharepoint list not receiving distribution group emails

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2016, exchange

We have a SharePoint list setup to receive emails and attachments which works fine when emailing that address directly.  However, we've recently added it to an existing universal Exchange distribution group and the emails aren't being received by the SharePoint server.  I've checked all sub-folders inside C:\inetpub\mailroot and nothing gets dropped in there.

I've confirmed we can add external contacts (such as Gmail) to distribution lists and those seem to go out without a problem.

SharePoint Version: 2016 Foundation

Any ideas how to continue troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create the identity for this email in AD and use it in the sharepoint list. This is seen as a security concern for sharepoint.

Comment: Awesome that seemed to work.  Is there any way to allow SharePoint created identities to automatically accept emails from distribution lists without creating a duplicate identity every time?  I'd hate to have to duplicate them every time if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Go into Exchange Management Console>  Recipient Configuration > Distribution Groups.

Right-click the Distribution Group that doesn’t work, and go into Properties. Than go into Mail Flow Settings, and go into the Properties of Message Delivery Restrictions.

Regards